# What is alternative way concat in js

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I'm having a problem with my function `flatten`

Here's the code:

```
    function flatten(arrays) {
    return [].concat.apply([], arrays);
}
```

There's an error of max exceed so i tried to change the function to this:

```
    function flatten(arrays){
    return arrays.reduce(function(prev, curr){
        return prev.concat(curr);
    }, []);
}
```

the error was gone but its too slow. Is there alternative code for concat.

Comment: Max what exceeded? Are there too many arguments, or is the concatenated array too big?

Comment: What do you want ? Do you want to convert a multidimensional array to single dimensional?

Comment: You may want to look into using underscore's `flatten`. See https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.8.3/underscore.js#L490. It gives a better performance of all three. JSPerf: https://jsperf.com/flatten-arrays-perf/1

Comment: The *flatten* function seems to work with up to 10,000 elements in *arrays* (Safari, Chrome, Firefox). There is no limit to the number of arguments in ECMA-262, at what point do you get max whatever exceeded?

Comment: if you want to save some time to implement it. try using libraries such as lodash

there is a method called flattenDeep

_.flattenDeep(youArray);
https://lodash.com/docs/#flattenDeep

Answer (score 5):

Try this ES6 spread syntax:

```
const array1 = [1,2,3]
const array2 = [4,5,6]
const array3 = [...array1, ...array2]
console.log(array3)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't handle sub-arrays.